# Consul Alias (CNAME) getting deregister

Tags: alias, consul, cname

I'm adding a Alias to Consul v 1.5.3 like:

```
curl -ks -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X PUT "https://myconsul.my.domain:8500/v1/catalog/register" \
-d '{ "Datacenter": "dc1", "Node": "consul_1", "Address": "someService.service.my.domain.", "Service": {"ID": "someService_consul_1", "Service": "someService", "Port": 443 } }'
```

nslookup works fine and DNS gets resolved.

But after some time Consul logs:
[INFO] agent: Deregistered service "someService_consul_1"
And the alias is gone.

Does someone know how to prevent the deletion of the alias?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the internal service name, registered in Consul, I'm now using an external DNS which points to the whole Dockerswarm.

This entry doesn't get removed and gets resolved correctly.

```
curl -ks -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -X PUT 'https://myconsul.my.domain:8500/v1/agent/service/register' \
    -d '{ "Name": "someService", "Port": 443, "Address": "dockerswarm.my.domain" }'
```